# Nullpointerexception: attempt to invoke interface method

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have a list view which when swiped on list item gives menu containing buttons (I have used [swipe menu ListView](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) library for this to work). Now when the list item is swiped and a button is clicked in it I want the list item to get added into archives and get displayed in another activity (for this I am using sharedpreference). Adding to sharedpreference and displaying into other activity works fine. But when in the archives activity where the archives list is displayed, I want to remove the list item when pressed on the button in swiped menu. Here the app crashes

**My activity where added archives are displayed**

```
 public class ProActivity extends Activity
  {

 SwipeMenuListView archiveseList;
     ArchivePreferences archvprefernces;
     List<CodeList> archives;
     SharedPreference shrdprefernces;
     FinalAdapter fnladpter;
     List <CodeList> codelist = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pro_layout);

    archvprefernces = new ArchivePreferences();
    shrdprefernces = new SharedPreference();

    archives = archvprefernces.getArchives(ProActivity.this);
codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();

    if (archives == null) {
        showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.nofav),
                  getResources().getString(R.string.nofavmsg));
    } else {

        if (archives.size() == 0) {
            showAlert(
                getResources().getString(R.string.nofav),
                getResources().getString(R.string.nofavmsg));
        }

        archiveseList = (SwipeMenuListView) findViewById(R.id.pro_layoutListView);
        if (archives != null) {

            fnladpter = new FinalAdapter(ProActivity.this, archives);
            archiveseList.setAdapter(fnladpter);


            SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

                @Override
                public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
                    // create "open" item
                    SwipeMenuItem openItem = new SwipeMenuItem(ProActivity.this);
                    // set item background
                    openItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xC9, 0xC9,
                                                                       0xCE)));
                    // set item width
                    openItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                    // set item title
                    openItem.setTitle("Open");
                    // set item title fontsize
                    openItem.setTitleSize(18);
                    // set item title font color
                    openItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
                    // add to menu
                    menu.addMenuItem(openItem);

                    // create "delete" item
                    SwipeMenuItem favoriteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(ProActivity.this);
                    // set item background
                    favoriteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9,
                                                                           0x3F, 0x25)));
                    // set item width
                    favoriteItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                    // set a icon
                    favoriteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.unfavorite);

                    // add to menu
                    menu.addMenuItem(favoriteItem);

                    SwipeMenuItem info = new SwipeMenuItem(ProActivity.this);

                    info.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
                    info.setTitle(R.id.beg_list_itemTextView);
                    //set item width
                    info.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                    // set a icon
                    info.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    // add to menu
                    menu.addMenuItem(info);

                }
            };
            // set creator
            archiveseList.setMenuCreator(creator);

            archiveseList.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
                        //ApplicationInfo item = mAppList.get(position);
                        switch (index) {
                            case 0:
                                // open

                                break;
                            case 1:
                                // favorite


                                break;

                            case 2 :



                                ImageView alphimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.beg_list_itemImageView);
                                String tag = alphimg.getTag().toString();
                                if (checkArchivedItem(codelist.get(position))) {

                                    archvprefernces.removeArchive(ProActivity.this, codelist.get(position));
                                    alphimg.setTag("noarchive");
                                    codelist.add(codelist.get(position));
                                    fnladpter.remove(archives.get(position));
                                    fnladpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(ProActivity.this, getString(R.string.archive_removed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           

                                }else {



                                    archvprefernces.addArchive(ProActivity.this, codelist.get(position));
                                    alphimg.setTag("yesarchive");
                                    codelist.remove(codelist.get(position));

                                    fnladpter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }



                                break;


                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                    private boolean checkArchivedItem(CodeList checkcode) {
                        boolean check = false;
                        List<CodeList> archives = archvprefernces.getArchives(ProActivity.this);
                        if (archives != null) {
                            for (CodeList codes : archives) {
                                if (codes.equals(checkcode)) {
                                    check = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return check;
                    }       

                    private Object getItem(int position)
                    {
                        return codelist.get(position);
                    }





                });

            archiveseList.setOnSwipeListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSwipeStart(int position) {
                        // swipe start

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {
                        // swipe end
                    }
                });

            // set MenuStateChangeListener
            archiveseList.setOnMenuStateChangeListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuStateChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMenuOpen(int position) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMenuClose(int position) {
                    }
                });

            archiveseList.setSwipeDirection(SwipeMenuListView.DIRECTION_LEFT);


            archiveseList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                                            int position, long arg3) {




                    }
                });



public void showAlert(String title, String message) {
    if (ProActivity.this != null && !ProActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProActivity.this)
            .create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    // activity.finish();
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                }
            });
        alertDialog.show();
    }


}

private int dp2px(int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
                                           getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);

}
```

}

**my logcat**

```
01-17 16:38:26.033 12088 12088 D   AndroidRuntime                               Shutting down VM
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.enlightenme.pac, PID: 12088
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.enlightenme.pac.ProActivity$100000001.onMenuItemClick(ProActivity.java:209)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView$100000000.onItemClick(SwipeMenuListView.java:78)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuView.onClick(SwipeMenuView.java:85)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-17 16:38:26.051 12088 12088 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poblem seems to be in this `if condition` in your `onMenuItemClick()`

```
if (checkArchivedItem(codelist.get(position)))
```

you have only initialised your codelist, but never set any data to it as you set to your archives list here

```
archives = archvprefernces.getArchives(ProActivity.this);
codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
```

So the size of your codelist is always zero, and hence it is giving `IndexOutOfBoundsException` to you in that `if condition`, I mentioned above when value of position is greater than 0, for your case it's coming out to be 2 for current case.

So setting data to your codelist and keeping a check inside your code that position returned by `onMenuItemClick()` should not be greater than your `codelist.size()` can help you out for any `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Hope it will make some sense to you now.

Comment: Yeah completely made sense changed the code like this codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>(archives);,, thanks bro. Phew

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid index 2, size is 0

Somewhere in your onMenuItemClick your trying to get an object from your arraylist but the arraylist is null. Log out the size of both the archives and codelist to make sure you actually have objects in them before you try adding / removing items from them.